# onTouch() not called when dragging item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I am trying to drag a recyclerview item after long pressing it to activate dragging. However, the `onTouch()` of the parent layout of the recyclerview item is not being called. I read from a post also asking about their `onTouch` not being called, and I set the `android:clickable` and `android:focusable` properties of the CardView (the only direct child element inside the parent ConstraintLayout which i attached an OnTouchListener to) to false, but the `OnTouch` is still not called.

**fragment_locations.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.LocationsFragment"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:id="@+id/locations_fragment_parent_layout">
    
    
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_locations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.74"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**location_item.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/location_rv_item_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="6dp"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/location_rv_item_card"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:paddingHorizontal="24dp"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_condensed_bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                tools:text="Location xyzxyzxyzxyz xasnxsaaskjdnasdjjkasjasd asdasd" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/location_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_for_image_in_locations_rv"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="190dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_condensed_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="8"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/location_image"
                tools:text="Descriptionxyxyyxyxyxyxyyxyxyxyxyyxyxyyxyxyxyyxyxyxyxyyxyxyxyyxyxyxyxyxyyxyxyxyyxyxyyxyxyxyxyyxyxyxyxy asjidojiaosdjioasiojdiojasdijoasiojdiojasdijoaisjod saidojasjiodoijsaasoidjoiajsdasoidijsad asdioasjioasoidjaijosdiaojsaoisdjaosijdioasjdioaaiosjdioasiojdioasdjioadio xuiasudhuiahiuxhauish xhauishdiuashdiuahs xuaishuiahxui asduhaisudhasui xasuhduiahdiuash" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**LocationsAdapter.java**

```
/**
 * Adapter for the recycler view in LocationsFragment
 */
public class LocationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationsAdapter.LocationViewHolder> {

    private List<LocationResource> savedLocations;
    private OnLocationItemClickListener onLocationItemClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private final OnDragStartListener onDragStartListener;
    private final OnDragFinishListener onDragFinishListener;


    public interface OnDragStartListener {
        void onDragStarted(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder);
    }

    public interface OnDragFinishListener {
        void onDragFinished(Map<String,Integer> newPositionsMap);
    }


    public LocationsAdapter(Context context, OnLocationItemClickListener onLocationItemClickListener, OnDragStartListener onDragStartListener, OnDragFinishListener onDragFinishListener) {

        this.context = context;
        this.onLocationItemClickListener = onLocationItemClickListener;
        this.onDragStartListener = onDragStartListener;
        this.onDragFinishListener = onDragFinishListener;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return R.layout.location_item;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public LocationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(viewType, parent, false);

        return new LocationViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NotNull LocationViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mLocationCardLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    onDragStartListener.onDragStarted(holder);
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    onDragFinishListener.onDragFinished(locationNameToViewholderPositionMap);
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return savedLocations.size();
    }



    public class LocationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private CardView mLocationCard;
        private ConstraintLayout mLocationCardLayout;


        public LocationViewHolder(@NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mLocationCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_rv_item_card);
            mLocationCard.setOnClickListener(this);
            mLocationCardLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_rv_item_layout);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int clickedPosition = getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
            onLocationItemClickListener.OnLocationItemClick(clickedPosition);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Are you tring to implement swapp of data inside recyclerView kind of functionality ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar I'm trying to drag an item to swap positions with another item in the recyclerview.  I have some logic that I want executed when this happens, which are the callbacks in the `OnTouch` method

Comment: Do  you know there is a method provided by the android team to do what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you talking about ItemTouchHelper and ItemTouchHelper.Callback? I implemented those already. The dragging works, but the 'OnTouch' is not being called to execute the logic I want

Comment: Yes , I was talking about the same . Can you express more about your logic

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar I read [this article](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.yt2erbko9) and I implemented my code the same way except that the OnTouchListener is set on a ConstraintLayout rather than an ImageView. I'm not sure if something else is intercepting the touch event. Once the drag is finished, I want to save that order, in which the items are placed on the screen, in the database, by swapping their id's, so that when I enter the app again, that order would be shown.

Comment: The UseCase which you have expressed works completely well with ItemTouchHelper . I myself implemented it few days back in my code . Just that I have coded in kotlin .

Comment: Do the xml files I posted here seem ok? Since it seems to me like its a layout issue rather than the logic

Comment: Using ItemTouchHelper you just need the recyclerview and bind it to it . There is no need for the xml to be correct / incorret . Tho the xml seems all good .